# How To Print Total in Every Page and Total Forward Every Next Page After Header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wkhtmltopdf

I want to print the total on every page and that total carries forward to the next page. I have tried the CSS with the page break function but is not working as expected. Also, I check with the

```
page-break-after: always;
```

[image]

So I want to print a total of 1000 on the first page before the footer starts and the next page header after will display 1000 and continue with all my pages.